# Diode drops in unregulated power supply

Tags: power-supply

Why are two diode drops assumed when sizing a transformer in an unregulated power supply with a bridge rectifier since there's only 1 diode between each transformer terminal and load? See for example p123 and p142 of Learning the Art of Electronics:

*"Tranformer voltage: This is just the peak value of Vout plus the two diode drops imposed by the bridge rectifier..."*

[image]

Comment: _"... there's only 1 diode between each transformer terminal and load ..."_ - Yes, but the transformer has two terminals ;)

Answer (score 3):

The load is connected to the transformer by 2 diodes. Inbound through a diode from the transformer to the load and the return back via another diode to the transformer. So there are two diode drops to take into account.

Comment: Yes, so obvious thanks and I even said it in the question but my brain was off somewhere else. I was imagining a sin wave into the transformer producing a sin wave output with each terminal alternating between V+ and V- of equal magnitude but the base of the load at ground instead of a diode drop above V-.

Answer (score 2):

As current needs a loop to flow, if you start from one terminal of the transformer output, trace how the current flows in the circuit, and end back at the other transformer output terminal, you will notice that the current flows via two diodes.

Comment: Yes, so obvious thanks and I even said it in the question but my brain was off somewhere else. I was imagining a sin wave into the transformer producing a sin wave output with each terminal alternating between V+ and V- of equal magnitude but the base of the load at ground instead of a diode drop above V-.